# Is it possible to customize meta query in this way?

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I have a custom post type called `promotions`.

In each promotions' post meta, I store two fields, `promo_start_date` and `promo_end_date`.

The idea is to only show promotions on the frontend, where the

```
current_date >= promo_start_date AND current_date <= promo_end_date
```

For example, if the promotion has the value of `2022-12-18` in the `promo_start_date` and `2023-01-08` in the `promo_end_date`, it will only show up on the frontend on the `2022-12-18` and then display till the `2023-01-08`.

I was wondering how possible it is to achieve this with meta_query.

```php
$args = [
    'paged' => 1
    'post_type' => 'promotions',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'promo_start_date',
            'value' => gmdate('Y-m-d'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '>=',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'promo_end_date',
            'value' => gmdate('Y-m-d'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I can easily implement this in raw `sql` but unfortunately I am tweaking a filter for a plugin in order to achieve the result that I need.

The filter is coming from the [Search and Filter plugin](https://searchandfilter.com) and its documentation can be found [here](https://searchandfilter.com/documentation/action-filter-reference/)

And here is an example of the code that I am trying to implement

```php
function me_sf_edit_query_args($query_args, $sfid) {
    // if search form has specified ID, change query args
    if ($sfid == 11000) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'promo_start_date',
                'value' => gmdate('Y-m-d'),
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>=',
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'promo_end_date',
                'value' => gmdate('Y-m-d'),
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '<=',
            ],
        ];
    }

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('sf_edit_query_args', 'me_sf_edit_query_args', 20, 2);
```

Thank you

Comment: Does what you posted not work??

Comment: @HowardE No, it also will show promotions whose start date has not reached

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet is incomplete, write the meta query and test/debug that first.

Comment: Ok, you just need to switch `compare` values, what value you have in compare for start date will go to for end date and end date compare value will go to start date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = current_time( 'Y-m-d' );
$args = [
    'paged' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'promotions',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'meta_key'     => 'promo_start_date',
    'meta_value'   => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'promo_end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will show promotions whose start date has not reached, which is not the intended result

Comment: so what are you trying to do?

Comment: For a recap, if the promotion has the value of `2022-12-18` in the `promo_start_date` and `2023-01-08` in the `promo_end_date`, it will only show up on the frontend on the `2022-12-18` and then display till the `2023-01-08`.

Comment: What your meta query does I believe is this `promo_start_date >= current_date AND promo_end_date <= current_date` and I want is this `current_date >= promo_start_date AND current_date <= promo_end_date`

Comment: This meta query will check for any promo start date greater or equal to today AND promo end date less or equal to today.

Comment: try again with the new method I updated in my answer