# Fix for select returning no result(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

This is kind of a continuation of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798555/is-it-possible-to-customize-meta-query-in-this-way) I asked earlier.

I am trying to implement a solution using raw `sql` on a WordPress database

When I run a query that looks like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM wp_posts
     WHERE post_type = 'promotions'
       AND post_status = 'publish')
  AND meta_key IN ('promo_start_date',
                   'promo_end_date')
```

I get the following results

```
+---------+---------+------------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key         | meta_value |
+---------+---------+------------------+------------+
| 6199874 |   54679 | promo_end_date   | 2023-01-01 |
| 6199876 |   87246 | promo_end_date   | 2023-01-02 |
| 6199878 |   87251 | promo_end_date   | 2023-01-03 |
| 6199880 |   87255 | promo_end_date   | 2023-01-04 |
| 6199882 |   87257 | promo_end_date   | 2023-01-05 |
| 6199873 |   54679 | promo_start_date | 2022-12-14 |
| 6199875 |   87246 | promo_start_date | 2022-12-15 |
| 6199877 |   87251 | promo_start_date | 2022-12-16 |
| 6199879 |   87255 | promo_start_date | 2022-12-17 |
| 6199881 |   87257 | promo_start_date | 2022-12-18 |
+---------+---------+------------------+------------+
```

But when I run the following

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM wp_posts
     WHERE post_type = 'promotions'
       AND post_status = 'publish')
  AND (meta_key = 'promo_start_date'
       AND CURRENT_DATE >= CAST(meta_value AS DATE))
  AND (meta_key = 'promo_end_date'
       AND CURRENT_DATE <= CAST(meta_value AS DATE))
```

I get an empty result set

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way to improve the no results query to get results that reflect what the snippet below indicates

```
current_date >= promo_start_date AND current_date <= promo_end_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause works on one row at a time. By definition, `meta_key` can have only one value on a given row. It cannot be both `'promo_start_date'` and `'promo_end_date'` on the same row. So checking that `meta_key` equals one value AND `meta_key` equals a different value will always be false.

What you need to do is check if `meta_key` is equal to one OR the other string. You can combine that with additional conditions depending on which value it is.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM wp_posts
     WHERE post_type = 'promotions'
       AND post_status = 'publish')
  AND ((meta_key = 'promo_start_date'
       AND CURRENT_DATE >= CAST(meta_value AS DATE))
  OR (meta_key = 'promo_end_date'
       AND CURRENT_DATE <= CAST(meta_value AS DATE)))
```

Alternative way of writing the same logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM wp_posts
     WHERE post_type = 'promotions'
       AND post_status = 'publish')
  AND CASE meta_key 
    WHEN 'promo_start_date'
    THEN CURRENT_DATE >= CAST(meta_value AS DATE)
    WHEN 'promo_end_date'
    THEN CURRENT_DATE <= CAST(meta_value AS DATE)
    ELSE false END
```

Comment: Thank you, Bill, that actually makes sense